# Collection can't get data in Template.mytemplate.rendered

Tags: meteor

I can't get data in Template.my.rendered ，but it is ok in Chrome's console.
This is my code:

html:

> ```
> <Template name="moitorContent">
>   <div class="tab-pane active" id="1">
>       ........
>   </div>
> </Template>
> ```

js:

```
    Template.moitorContent.rendered = function(){
         if(!this._rendered) {
          this._rendered = true;
          console.log(Svse.find({}).fetch());
        }
    }
```

When open the chrome with localhost:3000,

the console information is  "[]"

but  input  them in chrome's console

```
 console.log(Svse.find({}).fetch());
```

console.log can get data

like this:
[image]

Any idea about what I am doing wrong?

Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Hi, what are you trying to do? How about using a helper method for this? A note about your code: Isn't this._rendered always "true" within the .rendered callback?

Comment: May be your Svse collection is not ready when first render occur, try to add an optional function to your subscibe : Meteor.subscribe("Svse", function() {console.log("Svse Ready"});

Comment: @skeetmtp  yes,when rendered function was called ,the Svse collection is not ready.Any idea about it?

Comment: @Vindberg  I'm trying to construct a tree use jquery-TreeView at template rendered,and  `!this._rendered`  is always true .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you're using console.log before the subscriptions are complete:

You should find that using this should work if this is the case:

```
Template.moitorContent.rendered = function(){
    console.log(Svse.find({}).fetch());
}
```

To get passed this you can check whether there is data in there first/or use a `Session` variable to check whether your subscription is complete.

```
Template.moitorContent.rendered = function(){
    if(!this._rendered && Svse.find({}).count()) {
      this._rendered = true;
      console.log(Svse.find({}).fetch());
    }
}
```

A cleaner way would be to remove the `autopublish` package & make a manual subscription & subscribe. Use a `Session` to mark subscriptions as complete & check whether the subscription is complete in your `rendered` & use that to do your next task with all the data available.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Yes,I have already removed the autopublish package and called Meteor.subscribe. And when the template rendered function was called,the collection is not ready.I have no idea about how to make a flag  use Session.The class Deps can solve it ? The Meteor version is 0.5.7 in my app.